# How can I use the Corner pin node interactively?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, tracking

The corner pin node is used to distort an image in the compositor, but I don't like typing vector offsets manually. Can I do this with a GUI instead? In other words, can I drag around corner points on a screen, without having to re-render UV coordinates from the render engine?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Movie Clip Editor 'tracking tools' to provide the vectors.

1. Open an MCE window and import your clip. Check the dimensions in the
   properties panel by pressing the N-key. You should see the image's
   Dim x and Dim y value as "Size"
2. Add four trackers ctrl-click from top left clockwise to bottom left.
3. Open the Compositor and add to your image a Corner Pin node.
4. Then add a Track Position node / Map Range node (x2) / Combine RGB
   node.
5. Set the Map range node for the track position x value to Dim x (from
   the tracker properties panel), with 0 as the minimum.
6. Set the Map range node for the track position y value to Dim y, with
   0 as the minimum.
7. Send the Map range node 'results for x' to the RED input of the
   Combine RGB node
8. Send the Map range node 'results for y' to the GREEN input of the
   Combine RGB node

Repeat for all four corners, or duplicate the group of 4 nodes 4 times.

[image: Corner pin GUI in Blender compositor]

Comment: This solution is scene dimension dependent